# Simple Python string code\decode script question

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and for my homework I wrote a simple script that get a string from user like this one: aaaabbbbcccdde and transforms it to a4b4c3d2e1. 
Now I've decided to get things more interesting and modified code for continuous input and output in realtime. So I need a possibility to enter symbols and get an output coded with that simple algorithm.

The only problem I've faced with I needed output without '\n' so all the coded symbols were printed consequently in one string e.g: a4b4c3d2e1

But in that case output symbols mixed with my input and eventually the script froze. Obviously I need Enter symbols for input on one string and output it on another string w/o line breaks.

So, could you tell me please is it possible without a lot of difficulties for newbie make up a code that would do something like this:

a -  #here the string in shell where I'm always add any symbols

a4b4c3d2e1a4b4c3d2e1a4b4c3d2e1  -  #here, on the next string the script continuously outputs results of coding without breaking the line.

```
import getch

cnt = 1

print('Enter any string:')

user1 = getch.getch()

while True:
    buf = getch.getch()
    if buf == user1:
       cnt += 1
       user1 = buf
    else:
       print(user1, cnt, sep='')
       user1 = buf
       cnt = 1
```

so this snippet outputs me something like this:

a4

s4

d4

f4

etc

And in all cases when I'm trying to add end='' to output print() the program sticks.

What is possible to do to get rid of that?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the details but I can say that: when you add `end=''`, the program don't freeze, but the output (`stdout`) does not refresh (maybe due to some optimisation ? I really don't know).

So what you want to do is to *flush* the output right after you print in it.

```
print(user1, cnt, sep='', end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

(It is actually a duplicate of [How to flush output of print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function) )